# HTML file with an Iframe form, use button outside frame to submit form button with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML file which includes a form I created using formsite.com. The styling is quite limited so to keep the consistency with the pages CSS I have added a button with the correct styling outside of the iframe. I would like to click on the button with the id=formcta to submit the form which is created by form site using Jquery.

Here is the code which is generated on page load (I have removed all input fields apart from 1):

```
<form method="post" id="FSForm" action="https://fs4.formsite.com/res/submit;jsessionid=A07FC4D3E3825BF746905141537A7720;jsessionid=A07FC4D3E3825BF746905141537A7720" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onsubmit="return Vromansys.Form.processSubmit(this);">
  <div>
     <input type="hidden" name="locid" value="a938iH/02m2qhywlp">
     <input type="hidden" name="EParam" value="AT1kKIiyxDxmTDMP4mWxRYnjqh0-izcTGONOmeHEbhKIm44UQv8uNjFmDaWDB_-m">
     <input type="hidden" name="ElapsedTime" id="ElapsedTime" value="0">
     <input type="hidden" name="Referrer" id="Referrer" value="">
     <input type="text" name="subject_line" id="subject_line" autocomplete="off" "><label for="subject_line ">subject_line</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_table ">
     <div id="q0 " class="q required ">
        <a class="item_anchor " name="ItemAnchor0 "></a>
        <label class="question top_question " for="RESULT_TextField-0 "></label>
        <input type="text " name="RESULT_TextField-0 " class="text_field " id="RESULT_TextField-0 " placeholder="Name " size="25 " maxlength="255 " value=" ">
     </div>
  </div>
  <!-- BUTTON -->
  <input type="hidden " name="EParam " value="FzpUCZwnDno ">
  <input type="hidden " id="EmbeddedForm " name="EmbeddedForm " value="EmbeddedForm "><input type="hidden " id="EmbedId " name="EmbedId " value="551172803 ">
  <div class="outside_container ">
     <div class="buttons_reverse "><input type="submit " name="Submit " value="Submit " class="submit_button " id="FSsubmit "></div>
  </div>
```

Here is the code in my HTML document:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 pull-right">
  <a name="form551172803" id="formAnchor551172803"></a>
  <script src="https://fs4.formsite.com/include/form/embedManager.js?551172803"></script>
  <script>
  EmbedManager.embed({
    key: "https://fs4.formsite.com/res/showFormEmbed?EParam=PyBo85CFjhEWh5peMRvGtq_3bsAv-gQi&551172803",
    width: "100%"
  });
  </script>
  <div id="formcta" class="cta formcta">
    Get A Quote
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Jquery:

```
var formcta = $("#formcta");
var formIframe = $("#frame-one551172803");

formcta.on('click', function(){
    $(formIframe).contents().find('#FSForm').submit();
});
```

Here is the Iframe code:

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
var formcta = $("#formcta");
formcta.on('click', function(){
    var MyIFrame = document.getElementById("frame-one551172803");
    var MyIFrameDoc = (MyIFrame.contentWindow || MyIFrame.contentDocument);
    if (MyIFrameDoc.document) 
       MyIFrameDoc = MyIFrameDoc.document;
    MyIFrameDoc.getElementById("frame-one551172803").submit();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion however this does not work.

Comment: Do I need to include any PHP?

Comment: This is the error I get after clicking the button: main.js:41 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost/mango/main.js:41:21)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:3:6444)
    at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:3:3219)

Comment: I am currently not binding it as form site is building it for me.. Can I add this bind attribute with jquery?

Comment: That's fine. I just wanted to see how iframe is working in your case. Because I can't see any iframe in your question. I can just see the `id` of your iframe.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i have updated the question with the iframe code.

Comment: do you suggest binding it?